# Borrow checking differences between sync and async code?

Tags: rust, pcap, rust-tokio

Every time I think I understand Rust's borrow checker, I run into something like this which breaks my brain.

I'm using a third-party library that wraps [libpcap](https://github.com/rust-pcap/pcap) whose [`Capture<Active>::next_packet()`](https://github.com/rust-pcap/pcap/blob/main/src/lib.rs#L1238) call takes `&mut self` as an arg and returns a [`Packet`](https://github.com/rust-pcap/pcap/blob/main/src/lib.rs#L654).  If in a loop with a synchronous function (`sync_no_problem()`, see below), I store this Packet, the borrow checker works fine.  But if I take the *exact same code* and run it in an async function (`async_has_borrow_problem()`, below), the borrow checker complains that I can't reborrow the same function as &mut.  Specific error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `cap` as mutable more than once at a time
   --> src/main.rs:249:19
    |
249 |         let pkt = cap.next_packet().unwrap();
    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `cap` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
250 |         let owned_pkt = pkt.clone();
251 |         captured.insert(1, owned_pkt);
    |         ----------------------------- first borrow used here, in later iteration of loop
```

To really mess me with, if I make an async function (`nested_async_no_proble()`, below) call the sync function, the borrow checker is fine.  Can someone please explain to me what's going on here?

FYI: I tried to simplify the example to remove the pcap references, but I couldn't replicate the problem, so I assume it's something about how they work.  I also tried copious `.clone()` and `.to_owned()` on the `Packet` struct thinking that would solve the problem and it doesn't.

```rust
use pcap::Capture;

fn sync_no_problem() {
    let captured = std::collections::HashMap::new();
    let cap = pcap::Device::lookup().unwrap().unwrap().open().unwrap();
    for i in 0..5 {
        let pkt = cap.next_packet().unwrap();
        captured.insert(1, pkt);
    }
    println!("{:?}", captured);
}

async fn async_has_borrowing_problem() {
    let mut captured = std::collections::HashMap::new();
    let mut cap = pcap::Device::lookup().unwrap().unwrap().open().unwrap();
    for i in 0..5 {
        let pkt = cap.next_packet().unwrap();
        let owned_pkt = pkt.clone();
        captured.insert(1, owned_pkt);
    }
    println!("{:?}", captured);
}

async fn nested_async_no_problem() {
    // this has no problems!!?
    sync_no_problem();
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    sync_no_problem();
    // calling this has problems
    // async_has_borrowing_problem().await;
    nested_async_no_problem().await;
}
```

Comment: Side note: the reason `clone` doesn't work is because you're just cloning references. Normally you can get around this with `to_owned` but `Packet` doesn't have any such implementation. So in this case you'd make your own `OwnedPacket` type that holds `PacketHeader` and `Vec<u8>`.

Comment: Okay I checked this and neither compile. It just doesn't show the errors for the sync version until you fix/remove the async version.

Comment: 1) Thank you!  One thing that tripped me up is the default implementation of ToOwned for everything that implements Clone - from my perspective it's deceptive and confusing.
2) All of my code is async and so I never tried a version without the async compiler error - thank you for helping solve the mystery.